# Why does limit make this query faster

Tags: optimization, limit

Another question I asked here sparked another question.
I've got this query

```
SELECT `Qty`, `Invt`, `ClassNr`, `SubPartCode`, `Description`, `DesignCode`, `Measure`, `Remark`, `PartMnem`
FROM (`loodvrij_receptuur` lr)
JOIN `loodvrij_artikel` la ON `la`.`PartCode` = `lr`.`SubPartCode`
WHERE `lr`.`PartCode` =  'M2430A'
ORDER BY `SubPartCode`, `Qty` desc
```

The problem I had was that it executed faster in phpmyadmin than CodeIgniter. And I found out it had to do with phpmyadmin auto adding `LIMIT 30`

But what I wonder is, the query only produces 27 results. How does `LIMIT 30` make the query faster? I can understand that a query that returns 30 or more results can be made faster with `LIMIT 30`, but how does a query with less then 30 results get faster when you add `LIMIT 30`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're assuming the limit 30 only comes into play at the end of the query. If I asked you to look at all the people in the phonebook who's last name started with the letter T, and lived in New York, you'd have to pull out 50,000 names and then look at which ones are in New York. If I told you I just needed 30, you'd not have to pull out 50,000 names, you could look at people in New York, and then pick the first 30 who's name starts with T.

The SQL query will be resolved generally in the most efficient manner, so by adding LIMIT 30, things under the hood will change around to make your query execute more quickly.

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean, but if I look at my query and make an example. Say that you have two phonebooks, and have to look up all persons who's last name starts with a T, and that are in both phone books. You can't just stop at 30 at one of the two phone books...

Comment: That's true, but you have a foreign key relationship on PartCode -> SubPartCode so the two searches are not completely separate

Comment: Well, I agree, normally they would have a foreign key relationship, but in this database they don't, no foreign keys anywhere. (I know it's bad, but I don't make the database)

Comment: In your example above, SQL is probably going to look at every `loodvrij_receptuur` entry and look and see if there is a `loodvrij_artikel` to do the join. Once the join is done, it will check the PartCode is `M2430A`. So it has to join every row, then it checks which ones match the PartCode.
If you add the limit 30 in, it does not need to do that anymore. It can join the tables and start looking at them until it has 30 matches, then it will stop.

Comment: If you don't have a foreign key relationship, then it will be much slower. I recommend adding one if possible :)

Comment: But you still say 'until it has 30 matches', but it never gets to 30 matches... so why does it make the query faster? Why would it stop before it has 30 matches?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not how many results the query returns but how many items the query have to looks over. With LIMIT 30, what you ask is to stop running through after getting your first 30 results.

If you dont limit the results, sql will still searching until it reaches the end of the base. So even if you get less than 30 results, it had to work harder.

I don't know if I make myself clear, sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Okay, I get that with it stops after 30 results, but when you have less then 30 results, I figure it doesn't stop until it has gone through all results... why would it stop at a certain point? Since it hasn't hit the 30 results mark yet...

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't get that. That's strange indeed. How much fatser are you talking about ?

Comment: Query with LIMIT 30 is 0.1 seconds, Query without is 5 seconds.